# Powershell Script to prepend text to all files in directory with string

Tags: powershell

Powershell Script to find all files in Directory with the word "Sunday" and prepend the word "Test" at the top of only those specific files. My current script prepends the word "Test" to all files, regardless of if they contain the word "Sunday" or not.

The following script prepends the word "Test" to all files, regardless of if they contain the word "Sunday" or not.

```
if (Select-String -Path C:\Users\Test\*.txt -Pattern 'Sunday')
{

Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter *.bat | ForEach-Object {
$file = $_.FullName
$content = Get-Content $file -Raw

$prepend = 'Test' + "`r`n"

$content = $prepend + $content
Set-Content $file $content}
}
```

Comment: Why is `Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter *.bat` inside your condition?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why is `Get-ChildItem` inside your condition, it shouldn't be there, [`MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) instances already have a [`.Path` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo.path?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#microsoft-powershell-commands-matchinfo-path) to get the path of the file matching your pattern. You should definitely use [`-List` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3#-list) for efficiency.

```bash
Select-String C:\Users\Test\*.txt -Pattern 'Sunday' -SimpleMatch -List |
    ForEach-Object {
        @(
            'Test'
            Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.Path -Raw
        ) | Set-Content -LiteralPath $_.Path
    }
```